# how to implement a floating window in my navigator controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

how to implement a floating window in my navigator controller? i just know uialertview can push a window to show some massage.but i wanna push a webview to do something in the window. who can tell me how to do it? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UIView, set it up with a webview and then add it to your current view:

Subclassing UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

       ...// Code to customise your UIView can go here

    }
    return self;
}
```

Then add it to your current view where relevant:

```
UIViewSubClass *uiViewSubclass = [[UIViewSubClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[self.view addSubview:uiViewSubClass];
[uiViewSubClass release];
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Keep 'em coming, Rog.  Although others might not appreciate your answer, I do. :)